# Вызов метода изнутри, потеря контекста?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему в консоли пишет:

> Uncaught TypeError: commercialOfferModal.close is not a function

Почему в данном коде `self` или `commercialOfferModal` является `undefined`?

Если `commercialOfferModal.close();` вызывать снаружи функции `commercialOfferModal`, то всё срабатывает, а изнутри нет. Потому что `commercialOfferModal` является `undefined`?

```js
(function commercialOfferModal(){
    var self = this;

    $('.commercial-offer-modal_open').click(function(){
      $('.commercial-offer-modal__overlay').fadeIn(300);
      $('.commercial-offer-modal__content').animate({'right': "0"}, 300);
    });

    $('.commercial-offer-modal_close').click(function(){
      self.close();
    });
    $('.commercial-offer-modal__overlay').click(function(){
      self.close();
    });

  })();
  commercialOfferModal.close = function(){
    $('.commercial-offer-modal__overlay').fadeOut(200);
    $('.commercial-offer-modal__content').animate({'right': "-704px"}, 300);
    $('input').removeClass('error');
    $('p.error-text ').text('');
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Измените Ваш код с:

```
  commercialOfferModal.close = function(){
```

на:

```
  commercialOfferModal.prototype.close = function(){
```

Проблема в том, что вы добавляете метод к объекту, а не к экземпляру `commercialOfferModal`. Другими словами, метод будет доступен по полной ссылке `commercialOfferModal.close` и дальше, но не доступен через this, так как другая область видимости

Comment: А где в коде из вопроса есть создание экземпляров?